# I want to upload multiple images to the server using multipart using volley android studio

Tags: java, android, android-volley, multipart

I want to send multiple images using multipart volley in this format. the format that i have written below is in swift language:

```
multipartFormData.append(imageData,  withName: "nverness\(i).jpg", fileName: "Inverness\(i).jpg" , mimeType: "image/jpeg")
```

I'm getting multiple images from gallery and save in list. This is done from my side and working perfectly. I want to send this list of images on server using the format that i have written above.

My code is here:

```
   pickImages.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},100);
                    return;

                }


                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent,1);

            }
        });



 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1){

            bitmaps = new ArrayList<>();

            ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();

            if (clipData != null){

                for (int i =0 ; i < clipData.getItemCount() ; i++){

                    Uri imageUri = clipData.getItemAt(i).getUri();
                    try {

                        InputStream is = getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                        bitmaps.add(bitmap);

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Images successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e){

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                }

            }else {

                Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                try {

                    InputStream is = getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                    bitmaps.add(bitmap);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Images successfully added here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e){

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

how can i send this list to the server using volley android?